# Why do Giant Spiders from "Arachnids in the UK" specifically like Stormzy's grime music?

Tags: doctor-who

Is it due to the 140BPM speed? The certain rhythmic exchange of motion? Or some other reason? Is there a specific in universe reason the giant spiders specifically like Stormzy's grime music?

Comment: Because the writers needed a way to shoehorn yoof music into the show to help bolster its flagging ratings.

Comment: I had never heard that before and I hope I never hear it again. Between that, the Trump wannabe and giant Spiders, this has been the hardest Doctor Who episode to watch in my lifetime. And I kinda liked "Kill The Moon".

Comment: Oh no, that was alright. Those kinds of monsters and villains, I consider that typical Doctor Who. About average, I'd say. But what put me off was the totally unbelievable ending. Come on, couldn't they come up with _real_ reasons why those people kept traveling in the TARDIS rather than going home. Bah, humbug!

Comment: Because his Gregorian chanting music is mediocre at best, there I said it.

Answer (score 9):

They don't specifically like Stormzy or grime music in particular; they just gravitate to their food through vibrations as is mentioned by the Doctor. This makes sense as normal spiders move to the food on their webs when they sense the vibrations of something getting caught in them.

> **Doctor:** Spiders gravitate to their food through vibration.
>
> <sub>*Doctor Who*, Season 11 Episode 4, "Arachnids in the UK"</sub>

In actual fact they weren't even putting Stormzy on, on purpose, they put a radio station on: Raze FM. Just to be specific the track that is played is "Know Me From" so obviously Ryan wasn't targeting it specifically.

> **Doctor:** Any ideas?
>
> **Ryan:** Easy. Raze. Am I right?
>
> **Yaz:** I don't know what you're saying.
>
> **Ryan:** Yaz, you're so uncool right now.
>
> <sub>ibid</sub>

Of course grime music and Raze FM was chosen by Ryan and it is fitting with his character that he would choose this sort of music.

Comment: Probably also as it's a bit of "youth" music that fits with what we know about Ryan so far and also leads in to Graham's line of something similar to: "I can't believe they're going towards *that* music"... It did look like Ryan had his phone plugged into the sound system as an input source though... Given the impression the panic room was in the bowels of the hotel, and presumably heavily isolated internally (albeit the door was open) - I'm not sure there'd be (adequate) wifi/mobile or FM signals available - it did first strike me as he was playing something directly off his phone...

Answer (score -1):

Because they are British spiders.

Out of universe it's a nod to British pop culture and a thanks to the support of the Brits for *Doctor Who*.

Comment: Again whilst an answer to the question this is very brief and could do with fleshing out more. Why is this a thanks to Brits? Are there any quotes from the creators saying this is what it was meant to be?

Comment: Given that Doctor Who is produced by the BBC itself, I would tend to doubt that they would feel the need to offer "thanks to the support of the Brits".  They *are* the Brits.